# Textpad from Helios: Macro recorder and shortcuts as described

Tags: textpad

I would like to use macros. I tried to create macros (for example marking all between opening < and closing > of a HTML tag) and it works. I tried to use it as tempory macro using CTRL R to run it or to save it as "numbered" macro (MACROxx.TMP, eg. MACRO01.TMP). This is also no problem.

Now I want to give a shortcut to "numbered" macro. Following help I gave an Ampersand followed by character (ex. &W ) to the name of that macro (i. e. editing properties). But first of all there is no underlined W in the menu (Macros, ...) nor in the symbol bar and therefore I can't execute the macro.

I know there is a possibility to define shortcuts (Configuration, Setting, Keyboard, ...). But I would like to use the feature using &W as described in the help.

Textpad 6.1.3, 32 bit

Comment: Is this an unsaved Scratch Macro?

Comment: No its no "temporary" macro - it is saved as MACRO03.TMP

Comment: Try posting your question on the TP forums at textpad.com

One suggestion you might well get is to upgrade to 7.x 32 bit, which has been pretty rock solid

Comment: It works in version 7.40, but with small problem: The &W (i. e. displayed W) is not aligned with other shortcuts to the menu (the shortcuts are usually aligned to the right side of the menu). But I can work with that. Thank you Kennah.

Comment: Concerning TP forum: I tried to register me there, but I didn't get the confirmation. I think this forum is dead.

Comment: It's been quieter hereof late, but I'm a regular and it is very much alive.

Comment: Kennah, thanks. Could you please ask there, why new members are not accepted? I tried several times to register (last time in June 2014) and every time I never got a response. I would like to post my questions there but stack overflow is the only chance I have.

Comment: Looks like there is now an additional step. http://forums.textpad.com/viewtopic.php?t=12634

Comment: I'll try this. Forum mail after registration is somewhat misleading:> ---------- Ursprüngliche Nachricht ----------
> Von: forums@textpad.com
> An: X
> Datum: 27. Juni 2014 um 11:43> Betreff: Welcome to Community Forums
>
> Welcome to Community Forums
>
> Please keep this email for your records. Your account information is as follows:
>
> ---------------------------
> Username: X
> Password: X
> ---------------------------
>
> Your account is currently inactive, the administrator of the board will need to activate it before you can log in. You will receive another email when this has occured.

Comment: Received finally confirmation message from forum. As Kennah pointed out there is one additionally step in the registration process. Thanks Kennah for helping me.